# Onchange event not firing in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Please check the fiddle below in Safari,

http://jsfiddle.net/mothi_gautham/t5MEa/2/

1. Select a file
2. Click clear
3. Select the same file again

The `onchange` event will not get fired in Safari.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: BTW in you fiddle you should close the form tag properly , there is a typo and this </input>.

Comment: hmmm... this kind of thing can be buggy, from memory clearing a file upload like this might not be doing what you expect in IE and Firefox. The actually value might not be cleared. I may be remembering this incorrectly though, but something to check out

Comment: @Trott :Both on safari and windows, did you get the alert box the second time?

Comment: @musefan:Do you have any idea how I can overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure why your event isn't working in Safari. But are you able to use the [JQuery library](http://jquery.com/) - its a great javascript library that puts in a lot of effort to be cross-browser compatible (just a suggest for something to look into)

Comment: @musefan:I tried onchange() in jQuery. But that also does not work :( http://jsfiddle.net/mothi_gautham/t5MEa/3/

Comment: JQUERY version would be `$("#but").change(function(e){});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10430/discussion-between-gautham-renganathan-and-musefan)

Answer (score -2):

Try using the code below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var fieldsets = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");
        for( i = 0 ; i < fieldsets.length ; i++ ) {
            fieldsets[i].onchange = function() {
                Validate(); // Calling sample function
            }
        }
    }
    function Validate() {
        // Sample function content
    }
</script>
```